# GET request from browser works to download file to local but XMLHttpRequest Javascript script does not download file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest, aws-sdk

I'm having trouble with XMLHttpRequest I think, when I navigate to localhost/dashboard/downloadfile?file-name=hw3.txt the file downloads locally but If I use the function checkDownload() to start an XMLHttpRequest the file does not get downloaded.

Here is my client code:

```
function checkDownload() {
  const filename = "hw3.txt";
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = "blob";
  xhr.open('GET', `/dashboard/downloadfile?file-name=${ filename }`);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
      if(xhr.status === 200) {

      }
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}
```

And then here is my server code:

```
app.get('/dashboard/downloadfile', requiresLogin, (req, res) => {
  const userid = req.user.id;
  const filename = req.query['file-name'];

  db.getFileKey([userid, filename], (keyres) => {
    const params = {
      Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
      Key: keyres.rows[0].filekey,
    };


    res.setHeader('Content-disposition', `attachment; filename=${ filename }`);
    res.setHeader('Content-type', `${ mime.getType(keyres.rows[0].filetype) }`);
    s3.getObject(params, (awserr, awsres) => {
      if(awserr) console.log(awserr);
      else console.log(awsres);
    }).createReadStream().pipe(res);
  });
});
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: it doesn't throw an error. the client receives a 200 response without any file downloaded.

Comment: Ok, then you already have the page in the xhr object, try console.log(xhr.responseText) inside the if of .status

Comment: Xhr are not going to download the file, you should put a link instead or something

Comment: The text file is printing out correctly in the client console but the download is still not working. A link will not work I don't think because I'm using a database on the server to get the userfile's filekey in the s3 bucket and need to have user verification. if there's some way around that i'd definitely try it but i don't understand how that would work

Comment: As I understand, when you use blob you read the file as binary, see this example http://jsfiddle.net/woLkd0bz/ and change the url. To download, a simple link should work, like `<a href="yourfile.txt" download="newFile.txt">Download</a>` if the file is visible by the browser, you should download it in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. Instead of trying to create a read stream from `s3.getObject()` I generated a signed url to the s3 object on the server and returned that to the client, then used an 'a' html element with `element.href = signedRequest` and used javascript to click that element. The new problem I'm running into is that I can't figure out a way to set the metadata for the s3 object when it is initially uploaded, I needed to manually change the metadata on an individual s3 object through the aws console so that it had the header `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=${ filename }`.

**changed client code:**

```
function initDownload(filename) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', `/sign-s3-get-request?file-name=${ filename }`);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
      if(xhr.status === 200) {
        const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        startDownload(response.signedRequest, response.url);
      }
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}

function startDownload(signedRequest, url) {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = signedRequest;
  link.setAttribute('download', 'download');
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

**changed server code:**

```
app.get('/sign-s3-get-request', requiresLogin, (req, res) => {
  const userid = req.user.id;
  const filename = req.query['file-name'];

  db.getFileKey([userid, filename], (keyres) => {
    const s3Params = {
      Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
      Key: keyres.rows[0].filekey,
      Expires: 60,
    };

    s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', s3Params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        console.log(err);
        res.end();
      }
      const returnData = {
        signedRequest: data,
        url: `https://${S3_BUCKET}.s3.amazonaws.com/${ keyres.rows[0].filekey }`,
      };
      res.write(JSON.stringify(returnData));
      res.end();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a blob back from the server, so in order to download you need to do something when `xhr.status === 200`.

Something like this:

```
...
if(xhr.status === 200) {
   var fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.responseText)
   window.location.replace(fileUrl)
}
...
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No 
      function was found that matched the signature provided.
      at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange

Comment: I'm an idiot, obviously you have to declare URL somewhere, but I can't figure out the constructor since I'm getting a stream back

Comment: Try to use `window.URL`. Should be the same. The API comes with the browser. Here is the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

Comment: tried that and still not working. I put "console.log(xhr.repsonse)" after the xhr.status is 200 and the txt file is printed correctly but still isn't downloaded to local storage. 

is it something to do with the createReadStream on the server? Do I have to convert that into something that a Blob can read?

Comment: Just to make sure. You want to download to local disk? And not localstorage? BTW you have a typo in the console.log in your comment. Your server should be fine, since you can download directly on the url.

Comment: I want to download to local disk. The direct url is working fine, I can't figure out this xmlhttprequest for the life of me. The typo was only on here it worked fine when i ran it

Answer (score 0):

To download having the URL you could use the attribute `download` of `a` tag:

```html
<a download="something.txt" href="https://google.com">Download Google</a>
```

If you use `xhr.responseType = "blob"`, you have to do somethig like:

```js
function checkDownload() {
  const filename = "hw3.txt";
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.responseType = "blob";
  xhr.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
      if(xhr.status === 200) {      
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(xhr.response);      
      reader.addEventListener("loadend", function() {  
       var a = new Int8Array(reader.result);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(a, null, '  '));
});
      }
    }
  }
  xhr.send();
}

checkDownload()
```

But that code doesn't download the file.